# Command Failed: gradlew.bat installDebug error whenever installing dependencies like navigation, firebase, icons etc in React-Native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, gradlew, react-native-firebase

When ever i install any dependency in my react native project and when ever i use link command for e.g react-native link react-native-gesture-handler this causes me an error shown in the image [1].
It doesn't build the project shows the error gradlew.bat

The following code shows my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "navigations",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.6.3",
    "react-native": "0.58.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.0.15",
    "react-navigation": "^3.0.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-jest": "24.0.0",
    "jest": "24.0.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.51.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.6.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Apparently your `settings.gradle` file got corrupted. What is its content after the `link `command?

Comment: Yes this happened after the linked command

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If you have WINDOWS machine, please follow these steps:

```
Optional (
  Delete iOS, Android folders

  Run `react-native eject` ( that command will rebuild deleted folders for you )
)
```

Then :

1) `cd ./android`

2) `./gradlew.bat installDebug` ( with dot at the beggining )

Once it's successfully finished

3) `cd ../` ( go back to root folder )

4) `react-native run-android`

And fingers crossed for it to work as expected :) [for me it does]

Comment: In windows ```./``` does not work. Omit the ```./``` to run ```gradlew.bat installDebug```
Had the same issue. This one worked for me.

Comment: Optional (
  Delete iOS, Android folders

  Run `react-native eject` ( that command will rebuild deleted folders for you )
)
where did you get this?

Comment: Poorly described. The command in number 2 does not work

Comment: what about mac?

Comment: You have to add quotes `"./gradlew.bat" installDebug`

Comment: my issue was related to java-sdk version, which I changed to 8 and everything works fine.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I resolved this problem.

**Step 1: Open Android Studio -> File -> Invalided caches.. [ select all -> click Invalidated and Restart]**

[image: Android Studio -> File -> Invalided caches]

**Step 2: Open device manager -> select device -> use Wipe data and cold boot now**

[image: use Wipe data and cold boot now]

**Step 3: run `npx react-native run-android` in power shell**

If not build successfully. Then use the following step.

**Step 3.1: Open 2 PowerShell command plates then**

1. start metro bundler: `npx react-native start --reset-cache --port 8084`
2. run-android : `npx react-native run-android`

Or If still not built successfully. Then try following step.

**Step 4: Create another device with a supported API level. I used API 33 -> R 30 (API lavel). Now use Step 3.**

Enjoy and Happy Coding...

Answer (score 2):

```
cd ./android
create file file local.properties
```

then past this code `sdk.dir=C\:\\Users\\muhammad ali\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk` change location to as per your sdk is located Done.
you already have local.properties file good.
find similar file of code `sdk.dir=C\:\\Users\\muhammad ali\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk` change location to as per your sdk is located Done.

Comment: C:\Users\ashad\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
sdk.dir=C\:\\Users\\ashad\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue today... Wondering if you solved it?

go to android folder then settings.gradle file

You may find it on line 3

'..\node_modules\react-native-gesture-handler\android'

and replace all these backward slashes with forward like this

'../node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/android'

Let me know if this helps...

Comment: Yes this helped I replaced all the "\" with "/" and cleaned the gradlew by command gradlew clean and the code run fine

Comment: @OvaisButt thanks for reminding me to gradlew clean. I forgot to do that after running gradlew.bat installDebug

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you already have installed python 2 and last version of jdk
And make sure you have already set ANDROID_HOME

Answer (score 0):

I got this same issue in when creating splash screen set to the MainActivity.java. 
Then I downgrade the react native version (0.59.8). I didn't change the gradle version.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue just change the compileSdkVersion in your build.gradle file.

Open  android > build.gradle file.
Change compileSdkVersion from 29 to 30.
Change targetSdkVersion from 29 to 30.
now run again.

/[if this not working then checkout this link](https://exerror.com/error-command-failed-gradlew-bat-appinstalldebug-preactnativedevserverport8081/)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and used unusual solution but is helped me.
after create your react-native project, open android folder by android studio,
it will config your gradle Correctly and then you can run your app on simulator

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this error is caused by the debug keystore at least in my case that was the issue.

**What I Did:**

I ran this command to generate a new debug keystore

Windows Users:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias my-key-alias -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

MAC / Linux Users:

```
$ keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias my-key-alias -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

Answer the prompt questions.

When the keystore is generated successfully go to `android/app` and place the keystore file there while updating your `android/app/build.gradle` file with:

```
  signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('the-keystore-name.keystore')
            storePassword 'the-keystore-prompt-password'
            keyAlias 'the-keystore-alise-name'
            keyPassword 'the-keystore-promtp-password'
        }

    }
```

Thanks it! Just run yarn android again it should build now.

**GOOD LUCK!**

Answer (score -1):

I went into android studio and edited my emulated devices' storage capacity (RAM, VM heap, Internal Storage, removed SD card) in advanced settings. I believe I bumped every setting up.
[Virtual Device settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysNrq.png)
I'm not sure if this will solve your issue, however, it did resolve mine.

After that, I recreated a new project (npx react-native ...) then it worked like a charm.

As far as my computer goes, it has plenty of storage and ram so I wasn't too concerned with those limitations. Good luck

API = 33 
Android Studio Version = 2021.2

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).