# Can't start react-native as app:processDebugMainManifest FAILED

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, gradle

I was following the tutorial from [Setting up the development environment](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup) configuring the React Native CLI Quickstart of Windows and Android.

Whenever I run the command `react-native run-android` Metro starts in another CMD and Android Studios opens up, but this error appears in the original CMD.

```
 info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
(node:12644) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'padLevels' of module exports inside circular dependency
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
Jetifier found 896 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 12 workers...
info Starting JS server...
info Launching emulator...
info Successfully launched emulator.
info Installing the app...

> Task :app:processDebugMainManifest FAILED
Error 'C:\Users\xrafa\Documents\Android\AwesomeProject\android\app\build\outputs\logs\manifest-merger-debug-report.txt (Access is denied)' while writing the merger report file, build can continue but merging activities will not be documented
11 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 9 up-to-date

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\xrafa\Documents\Android\AwesomeProject\android\app\build\intermediates\manifest_merge_blame_file\debug\manifest-merger-blame-debug-report.txt (Access is denied)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\xrafa\Documents\Android\AwesomeProject\android\app\build\intermediates\manifest_merge_blame_file\debug\manifest-merger-blame-debug-report.txt (Access is denied)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s

    at makeError (C:\Users\xrafa\Documents\Android\AwesomeProject\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
    at C:\Users\xrafa\Documents\Android\AwesomeProject\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\xrafa\Documents\Android\AwesomeProject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:94:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\xrafa\Documents\Android\AwesomeProject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:186:9)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

I used [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54415332/command-failed-gradlew-bat-installdebug-error-whenever-installing-dependencies) and [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54707161/10339394) as a reference because I thought it was similar, but I got a similar error from what I got before.

```
> Task :app:processDebugMainManifest FAILED
Error 'C:\Users\xrafa\Documents\Android\AwesomeProject\android\app\build\outputs\logs\manifest-merger-debug-report.txt (Access is denied)' while writing the merger report file, build can continue but merging activities will not be documented

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\xrafa\Documents\Android\AwesomeProject\android\app\build\intermediates\manifest_merge_blame_file\debug\manifest-merger-blame-debug-report.txt (Access is denied)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
11 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 9 up-to-date
```

I also want to say that I already ran the command `gradlew clean` and same error.

Is there something wrong with the `gradlew.bat`?

Answer (score 0):

It's mentioning as `access denied`, try to change permission to android folder and see.

Comment: The folder already granted the SYSTEM and Administrators full permissions. I also ran the CMD as an Administrator. No luck at all.